# Where is the built-in Java Syntax file for vi?

Tags: java, macos, vim, vi

I'm using the default vi installed via homebrew on MacOS.
When I open a java file, I can see the syntax being highlighted as expected.

However, I would like to make some customizations to the syntax highlighting but I can see no syntax folder in my .vim directory.

Do I need to download the java syntax file separately?

If this is the case, where can I find the "official" or built-in java syntax file for vi?
I googled around for it but all I see are customized versions from individuals.

Comment: I suggest you use an IDE designed for Java.  There is so much more productivity tools you gain than just syntax highlighting. Unless you are only doing a little bit of Java, you will save so much time by using an IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There's no Homebrew recipe for vi, only for Vim or MacVim.
2. What you are using is not vi but Vim.
3. If you installed it with Homebrew it is not "default" anymore.

The Java syntax script is probably located in `/usr/share/vim/vim7x/syntax/`. You can *copy* it to `~/.vim/syntax/` and edit that copy to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create it yourself.  These links will walk you through what you need to do: [My Syntax File](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#mysyntaxfile) (for creating your own syntax highlighting file) and [My Syntax File-Add](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#mysyntaxfile-add) (for modifying an existing syntax file).  I believe that this is the [Java syntax file for vim](http://www.fleiner.com/vim/syntax_60/java.vim); however, it's from 2005.